# SendMessage and FireFox/IE/Webbrowser

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, sendmessage, hwnd

Is it possible to SendMessage to HTML Controls inside a Webbrowser component? If so, how can I get their HWND? I've been struggling with Spy++ and WINID,  and I couldn't access those controls HWND.

Answer (score 1):

IE's controls are not nested windows, so you cannot use `SendMessage()` to send messages to them.  IE draws its own controls and their internal workings are not public and are version dependent.

Firefox uses Gecko which, I believe, implements its own controls as well, so you will not have luck there either.

In a new question you should explain why you want to send messages to these controls as there is probably a way to do what you really want.  My psychic powers tell me using the [IAccessible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/accessibility.iaccessible.aspx) family of interfaces may be what you actually want.